# Signature Capture IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, uiimage, nsdictionary

I have a simple app where the user signs their name, once that is done it prompts for their name. Then another view controller appears where their name and their signature are displayed.

I can get the signature to work and display, but when I attempt to save the image to core data I get an error.

I've read the posts on saving an image to coredata but haven't been successful.

```
  #import "MyViewController.h"

@interface MyViewController ()

@end

@implementation MyViewController;UIImage (*mySignature);


@synthesize mySignatureImage;
@synthesize lastContactPoint1, lastContactPoint2, currentPoint;
@synthesize imageFrame;
@synthesize fingerMoved;
@synthesize navbarHeight;
@synthesize imageData;




@synthesize displaySignatureViewController;


- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //set the title of the navigation view
    [self.navigationItem setTitle:@"Sign here"];

    //create a save button in the navigation bar
    UIBarButtonItem *myButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                 initWithTitle:@"Save"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                 target:self
                                 action:@selector(saveSignature:)];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:myButton];
    //set the view background to light gray
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

    //get reference to the navigation frame to calculate navigation bar height
    CGRect navigationframe = [[self.navigationController navigationBar] frame];
    navbarHeight = navigationframe.size.height;

    //create a frame for our signature capture based on whats remaining
    imageFrame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x+10,
                            self.view.frame.origin.y-5,
                            self.view.frame.size.width-20,
                            self.view.frame.size.height-navbarHeight-30);

    //allocate an image view and add to the main view
    mySignatureImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:nil];
    mySignatureImage.frame = imageFrame;
    mySignatureImage.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.view addSubview:mySignatureImage];


}

//when one or more fingers touch down in a view or window
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //did our finger moved yet?
    fingerMoved = NO;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //just clear the image if the user tapped twice on the screen
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        mySignatureImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }

    //we need 3 points of contact to make our signature smooth using quadratic bezier curve
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:mySignatureImage];
    lastContactPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:mySignatureImage];
    lastContactPoint2 = [touch previousLocationInView:mySignatureImage];

}


//when one or more fingers associated with an event move within a view or window
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    //well its obvious that our finger moved on the screen
    fingerMoved = YES;
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //save previous contact locations
    lastContactPoint2 = lastContactPoint1;
    lastContactPoint1 = [touch previousLocationInView:mySignatureImage];
    //save current location
    currentPoint = [touch locationInView:mySignatureImage];

    //find mid points to be used for quadratic bezier curve
    CGPoint midPoint1 = [self midPoint:lastContactPoint1 withPoint:lastContactPoint2];
    CGPoint midPoint2 = [self midPoint:currentPoint withPoint:lastContactPoint1];

    //create a bitmap-based graphics context and makes it the current context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageFrame.size);

    //draw the entire image in the specified rectangle frame
    [mySignatureImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height)];

    //set line cap, width, stroke color and begin path
    CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 3.0f);
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    //begin a new new subpath at this point
    CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), midPoint1.x, midPoint1.y);
    //create quadratic Bézier curve from the current point using a control point and an end point
    CGContextAddQuadCurveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(),
                                 lastContactPoint1.x, lastContactPoint1.y, midPoint2.x, midPoint2.y);

    //set the miter limit for the joins of connected lines in a graphics context
    CGContextSetMiterLimit(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 2.0);

    //paint a line along the current path
    CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

    //set the image based on the contents of the current bitmap-based graphics context
    mySignatureImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    //remove the current bitmap-based graphics context from the top of the stack
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    //lastContactPoint = currentPoint;

}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    //just clear the image if the user tapped twice on the screen
    if ([touch tapCount] == 2) {
        mySignatureImage.image = nil;
        return;
    }


    //if the finger never moved draw a point
    if(!fingerMoved) {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(imageFrame.size);
        [mySignatureImage.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageFrame.size.width, imageFrame.size.height)];

        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), kCGLineCapRound);
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 3.0f);
        CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y);
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());
        CGContextFlush(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext());

        mySignatureImage.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    }
}

//calculate midpoint between two points
- (CGPoint) midPoint:(CGPoint )p0 withPoint: (CGPoint) p1 {
    return (CGPoint) {
        (p0.x + p1.x) / 2.0,
        (p0.y + p1.y) / 2.0
    };
}


//save button was clicked, its time to save the signature
- (void) saveSignature:(id)sender {

    //get reference to the button that requested the action
    UIBarButtonItem *myButton = (UIBarButtonItem *)sender;

    //check which button it is, if you have more than one button on the screen
    //you must check before taking necessary action
    if([myButton.title isEqualToString:@"Save"]){
        NSLog(@"Clicked on the bar button");

        //display an alert to capture the person's name
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Saving signature with name"
                                                            message:@"Please enter your name"
                                                           delegate:self
                                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
        [alertView setAlertViewStyle:UIAlertViewStylePlainTextInput];
        [alertView show];
    }

}

//some action was taken on the alert view
- (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView
clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{

    //which button was pressed in the alert view
    NSString *buttonTitle = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];

    //user wants to save the signature now
    if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Ok"]){
        NSLog(@"Ok button was pressed.");
        NSLog(@"Name of the person is: %@", [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text]);
        NSString * personName = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];

//        //create path to where we want the image to be saved
//        NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
//        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
//        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"MyFolder"];
//        
//        //if the folder doesn't exists then just create one
//        NSError *error = nil;
//        if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
//            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:filePath
//                                      withIntermediateDirectories:NO
//                                                       attributes:nil
//                                                            error:&error];
//        
//        //convert image into .png format.
//        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mySignatureImage.image);
//        NSString *fileName = [filePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:
//                              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", personName]];
//        
//        //creates an image file with the specified content and attributes at the given location
//        [fileManager createFileAtPath:fileName contents:imageData attributes:nil];
//        NSLog(@"image saved");

#pragma mark Core Data/ PNG Save



        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mySignatureImage.image);


        NSManagedObject *imageData =  [[NSEntityDescription
                                       insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"imageData" inManagedObjectContext:self managedObjectContext] ]









        //check if the display signature view controller doesn't exists then create it
        if(self.displaySignatureViewController == nil){
            DisplaySignatureViewController *displayView = [[DisplaySignatureViewController alloc] init];
            self.displaySignatureViewController = displayView;
        }

        //pass the person's name to the next view controller
        self.displaySignatureViewController.personName = personName;

        //tell the navigation controller to push a new view into the stack
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.displaySignatureViewController animated:YES];


    }

    //just forget it
    else if ([buttonTitle isEqualToString:@"Cancel"]){
        NSLog(@"Cancel button was pressed.");
    }




}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? What have you tried to solve it (debugging)? Please reduce your code snippet to the absolute minimum that causes the error. This is not a place for exhaustive code reviews.

Comment: Reduced code snippet to view controller causing issues. The error is redefiniton of imagedata with a different type.

Comment: I've tried converting it to JPEG instead of png and alternate forms of saving to core data calling the new object it is creating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned in a comment that you're getting an error complaining of "redefiniton of imagedata with a different type". That's because of these two lines:

```
NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(mySignatureImage.image);


NSManagedObject *imageData =  [[NSEntityDescription
                                insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"imageData"
                                inManagedObjectContext:self managedObjectContext] ]
```

You create a variable named `imageData`. Then on the next line you create another variable with exactly the same name. That's not legal syntax in Objective-C, or indeed in any language I've ever seen. This isn't really a Core Data issue, or an image handling issue, because you'd get the same error when redeclaring a variable like that regardless of what kind of code you were trying to write.

You're also not using either of these variables for anything at all, so you're going to lose the image. You probably want to

- Get the PNG in one variable
- Create a managed object in a *different* variable and assign the image as one of its attributes
- Save changes to your managed object context.

Comment: Thanks for the help. So I've changed "imageData" after NSManagedObject to "pilotSignature" it's now declated in my data model, and set to binary. I have a question though, how do I assign it the ''imageData'' as one of its attributes

Comment: You assign managed object attributes in more or less the same way as with any other object. If you have a subclass of NSManagedObject for the entity, just assign the value to the image property. If you don't, use key value coding, i.e. `setValue:forKey:`